# Unable to have multiple bootstrap modals on the same page

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm completely stumped. I have separate separate triggers all very similar

```
<a style="margin: 4px 4px 4px 4px !important" 
   data-toggle="modal" 
   data-target="#video_modal" 
   data-title="YouTube video title" 
   data-youtube-url="YouTube/url/">Montenegro protesters decry opposition's use of Serbian symbols
</a>

<a style="margin: 4px 4px 4px 4px !important" 
   data-toggle="modal" 
   data-target="#audio_modal" 
   data-title="Soundcloud item title" 
   data-soundcloud-url="soundcloud/url">Katarina Panic: Montenegro elections-The real winners are citizens
</a>
```

The modals are as below:

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="video_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item youtube-iframe" src=""></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="modal fade" id="submission-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item soundcloud-iframe" src=""></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the javascript which populates those modals.

```
//SOUNDCLOUD MODAL SCRIPT
$('#audio_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var source = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
  console.log(source + "Audio Modal JS");
  var title = source.data('title');
  var soundcloudurl = source.data('soundcloud-url'); // Extract info from data-* attributes

  //MODIFY THE SOUNDCLOUD URL TO INCLUDE THE EMBED PART OF THE URL STRING
  var iframeLink = soundcloudurl.replace(soundcloudrurl, 'https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=$1');

  //SET THE TEXT AND THE SRC ATTRIBUTE OF THE MODAL
  var modal = $(this);
  modal.find('.modal-title').text(title);
  modal.find('.audio-iframe').attr("src",iframeLink);

})

//YOUTUBE MODAL SCRIPT
$('#video_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var source= $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
  console.log(source + "Video Modal JS");
  var title = source.data('title');
  var youtube_url = source.data('youtube-url'); // Extract info from data-* attributes

  //MODIFY THE YOUTUBE URL TO INCLUDE THE EMBED PART OF THE URL STRING
  var iframeLink = youtube_url.replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g, 'www.youtube.com/embed/$1');

  //SET THE TEXT AND THE SRC ATTRIBUTE OF THE MODAL
  var modal = $(this);
  modal.find('.modal-title').text(title);
  modal.find('.youtube-iframe').attr("src",iframeLink);

})
```

Strangely, the YouTube `modal` appears and populates absolutely fine. However the sound-cloud modal isn't triggered at all.

I'm pretty sure I've got the classes and id's correct (because the YouTube modal works). But there's something I'm just not taking into account. Any suggestions?

Comment: For viewing media you can `one` have modal as in my answer below but for submitting you can have another one if you like to. Because submitting will involve some inputs and stuff i suppose - Let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do **not** need two separate `modals` on your page at all. I have `refactored` your `code` to have `one` modal which works for multiple things.

You can assign an `id` to your `a` element and check which one triggered the `modal` by checking it `attr` and you can apply the `data` accordingly to that modal.

Ideally, **less code** is always better to have dynamic results.

**Live Working Example:**

```js
//SOUNDCLOUD MODAL SCRIPT
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {

  var modal = $(this)
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal  

  if (button.attr('id') == 'soundcloud') {
    var title = button.data('title');
    var soundcloudurl = button.data('soundcloud-url'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
    //MODIFY THE SOUNDCLOUD URL TO INCLUDE THE EMBED PART OF THE URL STRING
    var iframeLink = soundcloudurl.replace(soundcloudurl, 'https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=$1');

    //SET THE TEXT AND THE SRC ATTRIBUTE OF THE MODAL
    modal.find('.modal-title').text(title);
    modal.find('.iframe').attr("src", iframeLink);
  } else {
    var title = button.data('title');
    var youtube_url = button.data('youtube-url'); // Extract info from data-* attributes

    //MODIFY THE YOUTUBE URL TO INCLUDE THE EMBED PART OF THE URL STRING
    var iframeLink = youtube_url.replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g, 'www.youtube.com/embed/$1');

    //SET THE TEXT AND THE SRC ATTRIBUTE OF THE MODAL
    modal.find('.modal-title').text(title);
    modal.find('.iframe').attr("src", iframeLink);
  }
})
```

```css
#youtube {
  background: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#soundcloud {
  background: Yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a id="youtube" style="margin: 4px 4px 4px 4px !important" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-title="YouTube video title" data-youtube-url="YouTube/url/">Youtube
</a>
<br>
<a id="soundcloud" style="margin: 4px 4px 4px 4px !important" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-title="Soundcloud item title" data-soundcloud-url="soundcloud/url">Sound Cloud
</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel1"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item iframe" src=""></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code in my local environment and the problem was with the id value of the second modal as which is submission-modal but should have been audio_modal as shown in below image [image]

Also there was a minor typo soundcloudrurl which should have been soundcloudurl
[image]

The full code is below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <a style="margin: 4px 4px 4px 4px !important" 
   data-toggle="modal" 
   data-target="#video_modal" 
   data-title="YouTube video title" 
   data-youtube-url="YouTube/url/">Montenegro protesters decry opposition's use of Serbian symbols
</a>

<a style="margin: 4px 4px 4px 4px !important" 
   data-toggle="modal" 
   data-target="#audio_modal" 
   data-title="Soundcloud item title" 
   data-soundcloud-url="soundcloud/url">Katarina Panic: Montenegro elections-The real winners are citizens
</a>
   
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="video_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item youtube-iframe" src=""></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="audio_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item soundcloud-iframe" src=""></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  //SOUNDCLOUD MODAL SCRIPT
$('#audio_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var source = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
  console.log(source + "Audio Modal JS");
  var title = source.data('title');
  var soundcloudurl = source.data('soundcloud-url'); // Extract info from data-* attributes

  // //MODIFY THE SOUNDCLOUD URL TO INCLUDE THE EMBED PART OF THE URL STRING
  var iframeLink = soundcloudurl.replace(soundcloudurl, 'https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=$1');

  // //SET THE TEXT AND THE SRC ATTRIBUTE OF THE MODAL
  var modal = $(this);
  modal.find('.modal-title').text(title);
  modal.find('.audio-iframe').attr("src",iframeLink);
});

//YOUTUBE MODAL SCRIPT
$('#video_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var source= $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
  console.log(source + "Video Modal JS");
  var title = source.data('title');
  var youtube_url = source.data('youtube-url'); // Extract info from data-* attributes

  //MODIFY THE YOUTUBE URL TO INCLUDE THE EMBED PART OF THE URL STRING
  var iframeLink = youtube_url.replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g, 'www.youtube.com/embed/$1');

  //SET THE TEXT AND THE SRC ATTRIBUTE OF THE MODAL
  var modal = $(this);
  modal.find('.modal-title').text(title);
  modal.find('.youtube-iframe').attr("src",iframeLink);

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you. Have a nice day.

Comment: Why two `modals` which can achieve same results with one modal and more dynamically. See my answer. Less code is always better. Also your code is not producing the results required by OP as there are other thing that needs attention. Just for your information :)

Comment: Yes I agree with that. Less code less bug. The reason that I posted answer with not much modification to his/her code is that I am just pointing out the minor errors so that the person avoids the same mistake in the future.

Comment: I agree, less code is better. It was only after I'd refactored just this way. How does one deal with having two modals. Let's say one for submitting data and the other for viewing media?